# In-app purchase issue with Mac app

Tags: macos

I am doing in-app purchasing in Mac as well as iOS app.

What we have understood when a sandboxed environment receipt is validated against https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt we get the status code as 21007: `CargoBayStatusSandboxReceiptSentToProduction`.

This works perfectly in iOS, but for the Mac app the result is different.

I have a valid Sandboxed Environment receipt in my Mac app which I verified using the https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt.

When I verify the same receipt with  https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt I need to get back the status code as 21007, but that is not happening.  Instead, I get the following response:

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Your request produced an error.  <BR>[newNullResponse]</body></html>
```

Basically if I submit this app in Mac app-store for verification and the Apple guys use test IDs, I will get a sandbox receipt which will fail with status code for production URL receipt validation and then I can fall back to sandbox URL for receipt validation.  But as described, the response does not contain a valid status code.

I have executed the following commands in the terminal:

1. Encode receipt using base 64 encoding, where `receipt` is the path of the receipt file:

   ```
     base64 -i receipt
   ```
2. Post data to verify the receipt:

   ```
   curl -d '{ "receipt-data": "<your b64 string here>" }' https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
   ```

   or

   ```
   curl -d '{ "receipt-data": "<your b64 string here>" }' https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
   ```

Response for production URL is :

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Your request produced an error.  <BR>[newNullResponse]</body></html>
```

Ideally it should be `{status code = 210007}`. Did anybody face this issue before? Or am I missing anything?

Comment: You may want to clean up the formatting of your question. It's hard to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For implementing IAP in MAC app is same as in iOS with below change. You need to make binary file after adding below code in

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

```
    NSString *receiptPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL] path];

   // Test whether the receipt is present at the above path
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:receiptPath]) {

       // Validation fails
        exit(173);
    }
}
```

This code will create receipt for your MAC. So, after it you can check IAP in your application. Please check that you are doing same.

Comment: I am already doing in-app purchasing and also able to get receipt. Basically my query is related to validation of sandbox receipt against production URL. I am expecting that I will get proper return code which is not happening currently.

Answer (score 0):

A sandbox receipt is different from an iTunes receipt. You said the error hapens when you send your sandbox receipt to https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt. But this service is intended for iTunes store receipts. Don't mix them up.